# Imagem não aparece no container até que seja dado um hotReload

Tags: imagem, flutter, dart

Sou novo no desenvolvimento em geral, desde já peço perdão pela ignorância.
Estou carregando uma imagem para um formulário através do filePicker, porém quero mostrar uma preview dessa imagem antes do usuário salvar. O problema que ocorre é que a imagem só aparece quando dou hotReload, sei que tem algo haver com o meu setState porém estou quebrando cabeça a dias e nada. Acrescentando mais detalhes a pergunta:

Tenho a tela principal onde mostro **todas os documentos na minha coleção:**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0zBG.png)

Ao clicar no botão elevado(+) chamo a tela de formulário(através do Navigator.push)  para adicionar um novo documento: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxJ7K.png)

O comportamento que era esperado, seria o seguinte: assim que eu selecionasse a foto, a foto selecionada apareceria dentro do meu container. Dessa maneira: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDniR.png). Só que isso não ocorre, porém ao dar o hotRestart tenho resultado esperado.

Aqui está a parte responsável por **selecionar a imagem:**

```
File? _image;
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  Future<void> _openImagePicker() async {
    final XFile? pickedImage =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedImage.path);
      });
    }
```

}

Aqui está a parte aonde estou **tentando mostrar essa imagem:**

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Material(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 20,
              left: 20,
              right: 20,
              // prevent the soft keyboard from covering text fields
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _titleController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Titulo'),
              ),
              TextField(
                keyboardType:
                    const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                controller: _descController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Descrição',
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: _openImagePicker,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.image,
                  )),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                child: _image != null
                    ? Image.file(_image!, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                    : const Text('Please select an image'),
              ),
```

Comment: Fala Daniel, bem vindo ao site. Não sei se entendi bem a ideia do seu código. Aonde a propriedade ```_image``` está? No segundo bloco de código, a parte que você quer mostrar a imagem chega depois de um ```Navigator.push```, o que dá a entender que uma nova tela é exibida. É isso mesmo? Então um setState na primeira tela não iria afetar a "segunda" (que é definida direto dentro do Push, o que pode causar também um comportamento indesejado). Poderia editar sua pergunta e explicar melhor como é o comportamento desejado e porque tem um Navigator.Push? Um abraço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `setState()` só atualiza o estado referente a própria tela que foi chamada. Como a parte que precisa ser atualizada vem depois de um `Navigator.push`, ela só seria atualizada se fosse feito o push novamente.

Para corrigir, crie um `StatefulWidget` que vai gerenciar seu próprio estado. Dentro do método build, coloque a tela que você indicou dentro do `Navigator.push`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TelaSelecaoDeImagem extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new TelaSelecaoDeImagemState();
  }
}

class TelaSelecaoDeImagemState extends State<TelaSelecaoDeImagem>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        [....] // Aqui é a tela que você utilizava dentro do Navigator.push.
    )
  }
}
```

Em seguida, traga as informações que essa tela precisa saber para dentro de sua classe de estado. Um exemplo é a propriedade `_image` e o método `openFilePicker`:

```
class TelaSelecaoDeImagemState extends State<TelaSelecaoDeImagem>{
  File? _image;
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  Future<void> _openImagePicker() async {
    final XFile? pickedImage =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedImage.path);
      });
  }

  [...] // O resto da classe que já foi citado acima
}
```

Pelo seu código, vejo que provavelmente outras propriedades também precisarão ser levadas, como `_titleController` e `_descController`, e os métodos que manuseiam elas. Porém como não foi especificado na resposta muito de seu uso, não vou especificar aqui.

Por último, no `Navigator.push`, retorne o widget da tela que você acabou de criar:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TelaSelecaoDeImagem()))
```

Acredito que isso deve trazer o comportamento desejado. Além de ficar mais organizado e cada tela ficar com as propriedades e métodos que dizem respeito a ela.

Como no seu exemplo as duas telas estavam acopladas em uma só, pode ser que a reorganização das propriedades não seja tão direta. Ou, se o seu caso de uso for algo muito mais complicado, uma solução de gerenciamento de estado mais completa pode ser necessária.

Para mais informações, sugiro pesquisar sobre gerenciamento de estado aqui mesmo no site ou na [documentação oficial](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) (em inglês).

Comment: Perfeita explicação e funcionou perfeitamente, muito agradecido!

Comment: Encontrei um novo problema ao passar as informações pra essa nova tela, devo abrir um novo tópico ou editar esse aqui mesmo? Grato.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho Deve abrir um novo. O foco do site é em "perguntas" e cada página deve focar em uma pergunta só. Um abraço e boa sorte.